# Is there any way to imitate paste in python?

Tags: python, paste

I want to create program that pastes special symbols when combination of keys is pressed. But I don't know how to imitate paste. I'm using pynput to make it press "ctrl" and "v" but it doesn't work for everybody in every program. For example, in terminal combination ctrl+shift+v is required. As I understand, pyperclip can copy to clipboard and paste to code, but not to another program. Is there any other way to imitate paste?

Comment: Kind of depends on /how/ you want it pasted. It sounds like you just want it in a terminal. Which at that point just print out the results from pyperclip's paste. `print(pyperclip.paste()`

Comment: Generalising that solution: have your program simulate typing the required input.  Then it will work with anything which takes keyboard input (this is how some password managers work, e.g. `rofi-pass`

Comment: The problem is that the symbols that I want to paste can't be typed with modules, they just print error when trying to. I don't want it to work only in terminal, but everywhere, including terminal(for example someone may need this symbols in terminal or have replaced "ctrl-v" combination to another one